# MVVM Modelview to View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

As far as i understand ViewModel communicates with View via databinding. But how can one create in ViewModel UIElements for View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ViewModel should not create any UIElements directly because the ViewModel should not depend on the View. The ViewModel provides data that the View (i.e. the UIElements) can bind against.

If your question is geared toward how to bootstrap a View, there are two approaches: View-first and ViewModel-first. In the former you create the View first and then create and bind against the ViewModel. In the latter you make the ViewModel create the View (through interfaces). Read more about it [here](http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/22/Which_came_first_the_View_or_the_Model).

If your question is geared toward composing the view of UIElements, this is done through DataBinding and the use of DataTemplates and ControlTemplates.

Comment: I really do prefer the approach where the View(e.g. in App.xaml) creates the first ViewModel, since that keeps all references pointed straight away from the View to the "lower" levels of code.

Comment: This is also true for ViewModel-first when using DIP properly. I prefer ViewModel-fist because the flow of the UI is often driven by businessrules.

Answer (score 2):

MVVM is a loose design pattern, it is accectable to put code in the code behind as long as it purely concerned with the UI only, just keep in mind that it may be harder to unit test.

And strictly speaking the ViewModel does not communicate to the View, there is no reference to the View in the ViewModel, rather the View reads data from the ViewModel and executes commands on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is dynamic component creation needs as I see.

You can put a Container object on a view then on modelView create UIElements and Bind this UIElement collection to Container's Content Property. But I think its not a good practice. This approach breaks Model and View seperation.So you need to avoid of dynamic component creation.

MVVM approach is a bit diffrent. Sometimes force us using tricks. i.e. Instead of using ListBox's MemberPath property you define a ItemTemplate and put ButtonBase elements on the template for supporting Commanding! Or you Extend ListBox and Support Commanding.

My offer instead of dynamic object creation. Use DataTemplates and change the binded members on ModelView,then the view will be automatically created for you.For complex senario's it could be hard. We do them all for the sake of keeping MVVM structure.